# How to do User Impersonation in Apache Sling or Jackrabbit Oak?

Tags: sling, jackrabbit-oak

Or more specifically:

Given I am signed in as the 'admin' user, and I want to to impersonate a user 'testSiteUser'

Given the 'testSiteUser' node (rep:User) does not have a protected String[] property called `rep:impersonators` set with a value containing admin

How do to update the protected property `rep:impersonators` such that it contains admin?

Once the user node has this set, I'm confident that setting a cookie `sling.sudo` should allow user impersonation.
[image: pache Sling Authentication Service configuration]

What I have tried so far..

```
curl -F:name=testSiteUser -Fpwd=testSiteUser 
    -FpwdConfirm=exampleSiteUser 
    -F'rep:impersonators'=admin 
    -F'rep:impersonators'@TypeHint='String[]' 
    -u admin:admin 
    http://localhost:8080/system/userManager/user.create.html
```

Which responds with 500

> javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: Attempt to set an
>   protected property rep:impersonators

According to the [JCR Spec](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jcr/2.0/16_Access_Control_Management.html)

> 16.3.12 Interaction with Protected Properties
>   Many features of JCR expose repository metadata as protected properties defined by mixin node types. For example, locking status is exposed by the properties jcr:lockOwner and jcr:lockIsDeep defined by mix:lockable. Changes to protected properties can only be made indirectly through a feature-specific API (for example, Node.lock), not through a generic write method like Node.setProperty. Such changes are not governed by the jcr:modifyProperties privilege, but rather by the particular feature-specific privilege, for example, jcr:lockManagement (see §16.2.3 Standard Privileges).

Perhaps the only way is to write my own Java code as shown below, but I'm pretty sure there should be a REST API to do this...

```
Authorizable authorizable = userManager.getAuthorizable(user.getId()); 
Principal admin = userManager.getAuthorizable("admin").getPrincipal();
jackrabbitUser = (User) authorizable;
Impersonation impersonation =jackrabbitUser.getImpersonation();
impersonation.grantImpersonation(admin);
```

Basically rep:impersonators is a read only property that is managed "indirectly through a feature-specific API" What is the API and procedure to do user impersonations using Apache Sling or Jackrabbit Oak?

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question, that you want to add an impersonator via a REST-call.

As you already found, all security related properties are protected. So they can only be manipulated via API-calls - and not directly written to.

But AEM already has a lot specialized REST-API's for its own user interface. To find them you should first perform the desired action on the normal AEM UI. Then check with the browser network inspector, which http-request was made by the browser.

In your case go to the classic user manager (http://localhost:4502/useradmin).

There you find the curl:

```
curl 'http://localhost:4502/home/users/J/JfiFIrTqxwUamu2BvWj-' \
     -u admin:admin \
     -F_charset_=utf-8 \
     -FmemberAction=sudoers \
     -FmemberEntry=alex
```

In the example I added for user `alex2` the impersonator `alex`. So alex can impersonate to alex2.

---

For the user `alex` you need the repository-path, which is encrypted meanwhile for security reasons. But this path is easy to find with the querybuilder. As example the following query:

```
http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?path=%2fhome%2fusers&property=rep%3aauthorizableId&property.value=alex2&type=rep%3aUser
```

or via the querybuilder UI http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html

```
path=/home/users
type=rep:User
property=rep:authorizableId
property.value=alex2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not using AEM for this. I'm using Peregrine CMS, which also uses Sling and Oak. Turns out, there is no need to set re:impersonators for admin. Admin just needs the cookie (sling.sudo set) and impersonation works!